# can't retrieve data from firebase on android studio 3.5

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> Screen shot here, this is the result of this Activity I already add few data on firebase with my upload function, it just show blank in the view.

[Screenshot Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGZ6D.png)

[Database rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxpm.png)

[Database data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LiGS.png)

> This is Activity,I was refer the tutorial on youtube but I can't retrieve data from firebase to my project.When I view the list it just show blank, Somebody help me.

```
public class RecipeList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    List<FoodData> myFoodList;
    FoodData mFoodData;

    ValueEventListener eventListener;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_list);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(RecipeList.this,1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Items");

        myFoodList = new ArrayList<>();

        final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(RecipeList.this,myFoodList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipe");
        progressDialog.show();


        eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //myFoodList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot itemSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    FoodData foodData = itemSnapshot.getValue(FoodData.class);
                    myFoodList.add(foodData);
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> This is Adapter

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder>{

        private Context mContex;
        private List<FoodData> myFoodList;

        public MyAdapter(Context mContex, List<FoodData> myFoodList) {
            this.mContex = mContex;
            this.myFoodList = myFoodList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_layout,parent,false);
            return new FoodViewHolder(mView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(mContex).load(myFoodList.get(position).getItemIamge()).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.title.setText(myFoodList.get(position).getItemNme());
        holder.description.setText(myFoodList.get(position).getItemDescription());

        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContex, detailRecipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("Image",myFoodList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemIamge());
                intent.putExtra("Description",myFoodList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemDescription());
                //intent.putExtra("keyValue",myFoodList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey());
                mContex.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return myFoodList.size();
        }

        public void filteredList(ArrayList<FoodData> filterList) {

            myFoodList= filterList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title,description;
    CardView mCardView;

    public FoodViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your error? Anything from logcat?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yeah @PeterHaddad That will be good to get notified.

Comment: Hope you have `defined proper rules of database` OR `taken Internet permission` OR `Internet is on` OR `given reference key is exactly spelled.`

Comment: @AlexMamo I try to upload a screenshot, and wan't confirm the JSON file is from firebase setup right?

Comment: @PratikButani at the dabase there  the rule i set both are true, take internet permission and the reference i checked on the database are exactly splled
Logcat there show nothing error on firebase tag

Comment: @Ashish uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post this code inside your onDataChange :

```
final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(RecipeList.this,myFoodList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

According to your code you just provided the empty list to adapter.

```
eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        //myFoodList.clear();

        for(DataSnapshot itemSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            FoodData foodData = itemSnapshot.getValue(FoodData.class);
            myFoodList.add(foodData);
        }
        final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(RecipeList.this,myFoodList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```